# How to use python's gevent.monkey.path_sys() with ipdb debugger?

Tags: python, ipython, readline, gevent, ipdb

I am using python's gevent library and do not want `raw_input` (or more specifically the event loop in cmd.Cmd) to block when awaiting user input.  So as a result I use `gevent.monkey.patch_sys()` to ensure that my other greenlets may run when waiting for user input.  Works great except that it seems to interact with `readline`.

For example, I no longer have history and auto-complete in ipython's ipdb debugger since the arrow keys no longer work.  This can be seen with this simple snippet:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_sys()

import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
# now hit arrow keys at the prompt
```

I get the following:

```
ipdb> ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
```

I have traced it to what I think could be an issue with python's readline as I know that ipython depends on it.

Also this appears to be a similar situation:

https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/6

but in my case I want to specifically use auto completion and history in the debugger.

I am running on OSX within iterm.  Is this something specific to a console setting?  Or is something in the patch fundamentally breaking `readline`?

Any ideas on how to resolve?